# How can I set background-position with repeat?

Tags: css

I currently have an image repeating on y (e.g. `background: url() repeat-y`), but I want it to start 20px down from where the div starts.

how do I do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe you should use `:after` or `:before` for this, because there's no need to add extra markup in your HTML. Like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/400/200) repeat-y;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

It works in IE8 & above. For IE7 or IE6 you can give extra `DIV` for this.

Comment: This is awesome; it works! Thanks, @sandeep. `right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0`, is this a way to "stretch" an absolutely-positioned container to fill 100% width and 100% height (starting from 20px, of course)?

Comment: While checking your answer discovered lorempixel.com awesome service, thanks!

Comment: right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0 is really container filler, tested ok in ie8. It also works like bottom:90px; This alone was worth gold.

Comment: This worked perfectly, then stopped with no apparent changes made. I had to give the :after rule a height to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think simply combining `background-position` and `background-repeat` e.g. `repeat-y 0 20px` will work. Assuming this [**jsFiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/P2jZq/) represents OP's case, the solution should make the green background starts at (vertical) 20px; the "Hello there!" text shouldn't sit on top of the green background.

My answer is this cannot be done plainly by CSS; meaning, you might want to change your HTML structure to accomplish your goal. However, I am starting a bounty hoping others to come up with better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the shorthand method:

```
.yourClass {
    background: url(../images/yourImage.png) repeat-y 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.yourClass{
    background: url(images/yourImage.png) repeat-y;
    background-position: 0px 20px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: this does not work (tested with webkit based browsers) background position has no effect. or teh repeat y goes beyond the start position.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and @TheLindyHop is correct, it has no effect in Webkit

Answer (score -2):

You just need the [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp) property to be set:

```
background-position: 0px 20px;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Comment: background position moves the starting point of the background, e.g. 20px down the page, but it does not prevent it from repeating *above* this point.