# How to repeat vertically the body's background image after a certain amount of pixels?

Tags: html, css, background, repeat

When I do this:

```
body{
    background-image:url('pix/image.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

It correctly vertically repeats image.png

My problem is that I would like some pixels of the background to be visible before I start repeating.

I've tried this:

```
body:before{
  content: "";
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  background: #f9fae8;
}
```

But the problem is that it moves all the content down which is not what I need.

Just to be clear, this is a diagram of what I need (made in paint!):

[image]

Note: I do notice that an alternative solution would be to put all my content inside of a container div, and give this div the background image and give it a margin-top of x pixels. The problem is the platform which produces the content doesn't like being modified a lot, so it would be great if this is possible altering the body without adding any extra divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `position:absolute;` to your `:before` . Write like this:

```
body:before{
  content: "";
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  background: #f9fae8;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

you can check this also [CSS: background position with repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761909/css-background-position-with-repeat/9142777#9142777)

Comment: That worked great! I had seen your answer, but I couldn't make it work with the after... I'll check out what is the problem and see if it should be closed as duplicate. Anyway thanks!! :)